# Java generics: The type is not a valid substitute

Tags: java, generics, interface, type-mismatch

I've tangled myself up in a bit of a knot with Java generics and I'm starting to get bound mismatch errors when using generic types. Could anyone point out where I've gone wrong?

Essentially, I'm trying to write a K-Medoids implementation that can work on any class of objects that can compute distances between themselves (e.g. either generic Cartesian points, or latitude/longitude points using a great circle distance, etc.)

I start out with this (which, I admit, may itself be wrong):

```
public interface IDistanceMetric<T>
{
    public double distance(T that);
}
```

I've then got a GeoPoint class that implements this:

```
public class GeoPoint implements IDistanceMetric<GeoPoint>
{
    private final double lat;
    private final double lon;
    
    @Override
    public double distance(GeoPoint that)
    {
        return GeoTools.greatCircleDistance(this, that);
    }
}
```

And then also several classes that inherit in a chain from this, like:

```
public abstract class GenericLocation extends GeoPoint

{
    private String prefix;
}
```

(Now, I get that `GenericLocation` doesn't implement `IDistanceMetric<GenericLocation>`, but if I try and explicitly implement it in the declaration, I get a separate issue of "cannot be implemented more than once with different arguments").

Anyway, the problem comes when I now try and implement the KMedoids thing:

```
public class KMedoids<P extends IDistanceMetric<P>>
{
    // ...
}
```

and try and instantiate it in the code using a base class of anything *other* than `GeoPoint`:

```
KMedoids<GenericLocation> kmeds; // bound mismatch error
```

This then leads to the bound mismatch error.

What am I doing wrong here? I've looked at several similar questions and they don't seem to be quite the same issue. I have a feeling it's something to do with the way I've written the interface, but I feel I'd just be guessing at this point.

Comment: `KMedoids<P extends IDistanceMetric<? super P>>`?

Comment: That worked fine, thanks! Is there a fancy term for what you just did? If I know the terminology I'll be able to read up more on these sorts of things.

Answer (score 0):

`KMedoids<GenericLocation>` would lead to a requirement for GenericLocation to be an `IDistanceMetric<GenericLocation>` which it of course isn't, it's an `IDistanceMetric<GeoPoint>`.

That's why you're getting the error you are getting.
Fixing it can get very messy, as tends to be the case with multiple layers of nested generics.

Andy suggested a fix (`KMedoids<P extends IDistanceMetric<? super P>>`) that you say worked, but that's the reason you were getting the error.