# The type is not a valid substitute for key events

Tags: java, javafx, event-handling, keyboard-events

I am writing a code for a simple web browser for my school project. Currently I want to have the code to be able to visit the site entered in the url when pressed the enter key. All of my buttons work (back, forward, refresh, etc) but I cant seem to get the keyboard event handlers working.

The error that I am currently faced with in the event handler is that it says "KeyEvent" is `not a valid subsitute for the bounded parameter <T extends Event> of the type EventHandler<t>`.

I have already looked at [Java generics: The type is not a valid substitute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69629669/java-generics-the-type-is-not-a-valid-substitute) but still not understanding why I am not able to put KeyEvent as an eventhandler type since it is a keyboard event.

This is the code Im working on:

```java
class KeyboardPressedHandler implements EventHandler<KeyEvent>{
                    
    @Override
    public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
        
        int key = event.getKeyCode();
        
        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER ) {
            loadPage();
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this looks fishy: _<T extends Event> of the type EventHandler<t>_ - note the different case of tee .. [mcve] please, including imports

Comment: actually, I suspect that the import is wrong (assuming that the body of the handler compiles) - __must not__ be the awt version of keyEvent